# Pandas: Joining dataframes based on different date periods

Tags: python, pandas

I have a problem with joining two dataframes. First one has rows that change day by day, and the other changes quarterly with a specific date that starts the quarterly data. I would like to add the quarterly data to daily data but don't know how could I join them.

First df:

| Date | Daily_value |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2000 | val1 |
| ... | ... |
| 13.03.2000 | val54 |
| 14.03.2000 | val55 |
| 15.03.2000 | val56 |

Second df:

| Date | Qarterly_value |
| --- | --- |
| 01.01.2000 | quarter1_val |
| 14.03.2000 | quarter2_val |
| 02.06.2000 | quarter3_val |

Output df:

| Date | Daily_value | Qarterly_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.01.2000 | val1 | quarter1_val |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 13.03.2000 | val54 | quarter1_val |
| 14.03.2000 | val55 | quarter2_val |
| 15.03.2000 | val56 | quarter2_val |

So every quarter data is added to dates from the beginning of the quarter to a day before the beggining of next quarter.

Comment: Welcome to SO; question has actually nothing to do with `machine-learning` or `deep-learning`, kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Hi Kamo, does my answer below fit what you want ?  Feel free to let me know if any clarification or fine-tuning is required.

Comment: The answer worked like a charm. Thank you, you saved me a lot of time with a solution that simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can merge the 2 dataframes with outer merge using [`.merge()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html). Then, forward fill for undefined values of `Qarterly_value` using [`ffill()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html), as follows:

```
df_out = df1.merge(df2, how='outer')

df_out['Qarterly_value'] = df_out['Qarterly_value'].ffill()
```

**Result:**

```
print(df_out)

         Date Daily_value Qarterly_value
0  01.01.2000        val1   quarter1_val
1  13.03.2000       val54   quarter1_val
2  14.03.2000       val55   quarter2_val
3  15.03.2000       val56   quarter2_val
4  02.06.2000       valxx   quarter3_val
```